# how to change format of tab set panel

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change font type, size, colour and background colour of tabs in tabset panel.

My code for tabset panel is below. Thanks.

```
tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel(
                            "Scatter Plot",
                            selectInput(
                                selected = c("United Kingdom"),
                                inputId = "country2",
                                label = "Click in box to select Country/s: ",
                                multiple = TRUE,
                                choices = sort(unique(df1$Country.x))
                                
                            ),
                            plotOutput("panel_plot", brush = "brushed", height = 500),
                            verbatimTextOutput("info")
                        ),
                        tabPanel("Scatter Plot - Summary",
                                 verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                        tabPanel(
                            "TreeMap - Continental",
                            selectInput(
                                selected = c("Europe"),
                                inputId = "continent_2",
                                label = "Select Continent",
                                multiple = FALSE,
                                choices = sort(unique(df1$Continent))
                                
                            ),
                            highchartOutput("tmap1", height = 550)
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: Youn probably want to try: https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/bslib.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
  tags$style(
            ".nav-tabs {
                        background-color: #40ff00;
                        }

        .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active:hover a, .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active a {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
        }

        .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active {
            border-top-color: #FFF;
        }"
        )
```